# CSS3 Snow animation - invalid property value

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a problem with CSS3 animation on my WordPress [blog](http://blog.alpner.com/). I inserted the snow animation into custom CSS and applied it on the `#masthead div`. Background images show up, but the animation does not start.

When I click on the Inspect Element in Google Chrome, sign next to the animation property says "Invalid property value"

I have no clue, what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The animation property syntax in question is not supported in that version of Chrome. Use the following process:

- Type `document.body.style.` in the console to see an autocomplete of the property names
- Lookup the browser support and syntax on a [support matrix](http://www.css3files.com/animation/) reference site
- Compare sample code from [a CSS3 demo](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/keyframe-gallery.html) aggregation site

**References**

- [HTMLElement.style attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice.

I solved the problem just by separating animation CSS from the main style.css and then putting it in a seperate file before main css in header.